# How to reduce http request using PHP when HTML Doc loads JS or CSS?

Tags: javascript, php, css, http-request

I use [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) to reduce the http request when HTML needs to load JavaScript or CSS.  However, I would like to further reduce the http request.
  *The question is:* Is it necessary using PHP to output content like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:Application/x-javascript;Charset=utf-8');
echo '<script src="text/javascript>';
foreach ($files as $file) {
  echo file_get_contents();
}
echo '</script>';
?>
```

What is the difference between using `<script>` tags and PHP output?

Any answer will be helpful, Thanks!

Comment: If it is within the same website then you can do it either way.

One way I had it on a website was to minify all the css, and output on the actual page in tags. This reduced the HTTP requests to 1. This happened dynamically and was cached until a change happened to the CSS file.

Comment: I've no idea what you are trying to ask, but the `application/javascript` mime type hasn't been experimental for many years (get rid of the `x-`) and a JavaScript file should contain JavaScript not bits of HTML.

Comment: @Quentin, Thank your! What confuses me is that using PHP to output content or not when HTTP request `get` JavaScript or  CSS file?

Comment: I have no idea what is confusing about that. You can respond to a request with a static file or with data generated by PHP as dictated by your needs and desires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on Expiration Headers. With this approach your client (browser) will load JS/CSS files only for the first time and then it will keep them in cache

Example how to do it with .htaccess file:
https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/dac15682b35ad69f519205e1b82694d0cab189ca/.htaccess#L192

Keep in mind, that when clients store your file in cache they won't send requests for this file again till it expire - even if you change content in this files. The best approach is appending something to file name every time when you change them, for example :

```
<script src="path/to/js/file.js?t={TIMESTAMP}" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

where {TIMESTAMP} is a timestamp of last deployment/file modification